# Named router outlet not displaying anything

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, router-outlet

im currently working on an angular project where i need two router outlets, one is the primary outlet for loading main pages and the dashboard page, and the other that i called "mainview" loads the component selected in the sidebar of the dashbaord page (currently only testing with url).

Here's the routing module i created:

```
import { OrdersComponent } from './pages/orders/orders.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthentificationComponent } from './pages/authentification/authentification.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './pages/index/index.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: IndexComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},


  {path: 'login', component: AuthentificationComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'orders', component: OrdersComponent, outlet: 'mainview'},

  {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and here's the dashboard page that loads the secondary outlet:

```html
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
    <mat-drawer mode="side" opened>
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
        <router-outlet name="mainview"></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

i tried loading the orders components in the mainview page using this url:

```
http://localhost:4200/dashboard(mainview:orders)
```

Here's the dashboard page, the white space is where the "mainview" outlet content should display:
[image: dashboard image]

but it stays blank, maybe im making an obvious error, but this is my first time working with named router outlets, please let me know how i can get the secondary outlet "mainview" to display the orders component.
And thanks

Comment: I think ‘orders’ path should be a child of dashboard path.

Comment: making it a child isn't what im trying to do, check out the image i just added the the post, what im trying to do is make the orders component show up in the white space using a the secondary router outlet "mainview", child indenting doesn't work here since its the same page, i dont want to redirect the user to a different page, i just want to show him the "orders" page in the white space using the router. i looked up a tutorial on named routers and what i did resembles what they did, but they secondary router outlet content is still blank.

Comment: Have you checked your console log in the Browser? It maybe just be an error or a missing dependency. Could it be that your application cannot find the OrdersComponent?

Comment: Maybe you have a misunderstanding about what I meant with child(ren)? Because it is part of dashboard, it should be part of dashboard routing (using children: []). As you have your routing now, there is no way for Angular to know it is part of dashboard, it’s just it’s own route now. Does that make sense?

Comment: @LuisAceituno the console is clean, so i guess it finds the component but doesnt display it or?

Comment: @MikeOne oh you're right im sorry i guess it does work like that.

Comment: @MikeOne but i thought u could make named outlets no? i think its best to split the view to two outlets or?

Comment: Yes you can, you did that fine and still need that to load the child in.

Answer (score 5):

If you're loading the `OrdersComponent` *inside* the `DashboardComponent` then you need to first load the `DashboardComponent` and then the `OrdersComponent`. The way you have it set up would only work if the dashboard outlet and the mainview outlet were both in your top level component. For nested `router-outlet`s use the `children` property.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: IndexComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'orders',
        component: OrdersComponent,
        outlet: 'mainview',
      },
    ],
  },
  {path: 'orders', component: OrdersComponent, outlet: 'mainview'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

You would navigate like this: `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/(mainview:orders)`

In this case the outlet name is unnecessary since it's the only `router-outlet` in the dashboard component.